# Performance difference between forEach and for (var o in objs)

Tags: dart

Is there any difference in execution speed and/or memory consumption between:

```
for (var o in objs) { ... }
```

and

```
objs.forEach((o) { ... });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Lists and Queues, the latter tends to be about 2 to 2.5 times faster on my machine, using the Dart VM.  This makes sense because `forEach` iterates internally with some variant of `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`, while `for-in` iterates with `Iterator.moveNext()`.

Using `dart2js` and running on `d8`, `forEach` is about 1.3 times faster on my machine for Queues, but 1.2 times *slower* for Lists.

As always, when performance is an especially important consideration, it makes sense to benchmark your real-world code.

I'd consider it a bug if there were a substantial difference in memory consumption.

**Update:** Florian Loitsch explains in the comments below:

> The `moveNext` method is currently not inlined (too large). This is something that should change very soon, after which both should be roughly at the same speed.

Comment: Have you tested on the VM or dart2js ?

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin Just the VM.

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin With `dart2js`, `forEach` is still faster, but only by a factor of about 1.3.

Comment: I'm surprised there is a difference. I'd expect the optimiser to be able to handle this. If there is a difference now, I'd expect it to go away as the VM and dart2js progress.

Comment: The `moveNext` method is currently not inlined (too large). This is something that should change very soon, after which both should be roughly at the same speed.

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch Thanks, Florian, that's great info.